# Python locale-aware string comparison

Tags: python, string

In German, the eszett letter "ß" is equivalent to "ss".

Python allows locale-aware string comparison, like so:

```
>>> foo = u'strasse'
>>> bar = u'stra\xdfe'
>>> print(bar.encode('utf-8'))
straße
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
'de_DE'
>>> locale.strcoll(foo, bar)
-12
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8')
'de_DE.utf8'
>>> locale.strcoll(foo, bar)
-28
```

How can I compare foo and bar and know that they are, in fact, equivalent?

(And why does locale.strcoll(foo, bar) not return 0 when the locale is set to German?)

Just to clarify, I'm interested in a generic solution, not specific to German. Java's solution to locale-aware string comparison is its [java.text.Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) class. C#'s solution is its [System.Globalization.CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165449.aspx) class. Does Python have something like this? (And if not, shouldn't it?)

For the curious, here's an example of using Collator in Java:

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CompareStrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collator coll = Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
        coll.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
        if (coll.compare("strasse", "straße") == 0) {
            System.out.println("Strings are equivalent");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Strings are not equivalent");
        }
    }
}
```

Output is "Strings are equivalent".

Comment: may be this [reciepe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/251871-latin1-to-ascii-the-unicode-hammer/) may be of help

Comment: Thanks alko, that works for German! I'd still like to know if there is a more generic solution that works for languages that don't use a Latin alphabet. e.g. Traditional Chinese and Simplified Chinese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) module.

```
from unidecode import unidecode
print unidecode(u'stra\xdfe')
```

Output:

```
strasse
```

This process of conversion from one script to another is refered to as [transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want external modules, What about this hack :

```
def isEquivalent(str1, str2):
    return ( locale.strxfrm(str2[:-1]) < locale.strxfrm(str1) <= locale.strxfrm(str2) < locale.strxfrm(str1+"0") 
    or 
    locale.strxfrm(str1[:-1]) < locale.strxfrm(str2) <= locale.strxfrm(str1) < locale.strxfrm(str2+"0") )
```

This also considers accents or umlaut as being equivalent.