# Why isn't locale.strxfrm("Gè") a prefix of locale.strxfrm("Gène")) with locale "fr_FR.UTF-8"?

Tags: python, string, utf-8, comparison, locale

The code here is in Python, but the behavior should be the same in C/C++ using *locale*.

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "fr_FR.UTF-8")
>>> locale.strxfrm("Gène").startswith(locale.strxfrm("Gè"))
False
```

I know it is not supposed to be used that way, but I'm wondering what is going on...

**Context:** 
I have an array of strxfrm-transformed strings and an normal input text. I want to know which strxfrm-transformed strings started with text *before* transformation. Is it doable at all ? How ?

**Bonus Question:**

Can we get the per-locale list of equivalent letters ? Can we check for equivalent strings ?

What I mean is:
 
In **`"de_DE.UTF8"`**, can I get something like

```
locale.strxfrm("Wissen").startswith(locale.strxfrm("Wiß"))
```

returning True ?

Since `"ß" and "ss" are equivalent` in sorting (unless it's the only difference):

```
> locale.strxfrm("Wiessen") < locale.strxfrm("Wießen") < locale.strxfrm("Wiessen0")
True
```

Same for "œ" and "oe" in French.

**EDIT**: Regarding the bonus, I saw [Python locale-aware string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830643/python-locale-aware-string-comparison?rq=1) but the answer relies on 3rd party libs, so I proposed a workaround hacked function :

```
def isEquivalent(str1, str2):
    return ( locale.strxfrm(str2[:-1]) < locale.strxfrm(str1) <= locale.strxfrm(str2) < locale.strxfrm(str1+"0") 
    or 
    locale.strxfrm(str1[:-1]) < locale.strxfrm(str2) <= locale.strxfrm(str1) < locale.strxfrm(str2+"0") )
```

Comment: You should mention the programming language.

Comment: In the tags on top of in the question itself ? The problem is the same in all language using locale

Comment: Mention the language at least once, either in the title or the tags, as these are the things displayed in the overview. Mentioning it in the question makes it easier but is IMHO not necessary. You should really check whether your statement is true for C++, Java or JavaScript. Maybe you are wrong. And your assumption doestn't help you, does it?

Comment: As I understand it, my problem is with "locale", so that's true for C/C++/Python. I thought I might have more potential solutions by not stating the language, let's tag it Python if you think it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very interesting question!
This answer is not canonical, I think `glibc-dev` would be the best forum for that.

#### TL;DR

The only requirement for `strxfrm` is this:

```c
strcmp(strxfrm(a), strxfrm(b)) == strcoll(a, b)
```

What `strxfrm` allows is to export the relative order of things to another (dumber) system, for example, to maintain a secondary index in a database table.

#### Let's test it

Let's examine **Python3** (Python3.9, OSX, composed normal form):

```py
>>> locale.strxfrm(unicodedata.normalize("NFC", "Gène"))
'Jëqh\x01Jëqh'
>>> locale.strxfrm(unicodedata.normalize("NFC", "Gè"))
'Jë\x01Jë'
```

If you were to break the output by the `<SOH>` byte, you'd actually get a valid substring.

I don't know the significance of the the output essentially repeated on both sides of the separator character.

Python 3 **NFD** appears to follow same semantics, but different output, which I guess only underlines how important it is to normalise your text

```py
>>> locale.strxfrm(unicodedata.normalize("NFD", "Gène"))
'Jhăqh\x01JhЃqh'
>>> locale.strxfrm(unicodedata.normalize("NFD", "Gè"))
'Jhă\x01JhЃ'
```

**Other scripts** have funkier output, here's Japanese in Japanese locale:

```py
>>> locale.strxfrm(unicodedata.normalize("NFC", "村上  春樹"))
'ăă#ăă\x01桔伍#木欼'
>>> locale.strxfrm(unicodedata.normalize("NFC", "村上春樹"))
'ăăăă\x01桔伍木欼'
>>> locale.strxfrm(unicodedata.normalize("NFC", "村上"))
'ăă\x01桔伍'
>>> 'ăăăă\x01桔伍木欼' > 'ăă#ăă\x01桔伍#木欼' > 'ăă\x01桔伍'
True
```

**Python2** has a different format where the content is also repeated, but it's unclear how to detect the separator. So, let's not use Python 2, it's already EOL

```py
>>> locale.strxfrm(unicodedata.normalize("NFC", u"Gène").encode("utf-8"))
'0019003Z001`001W00000019003Z001`001W'
>>> locale.strxfrm(unicodedata.normalize("NFC", u"Gè").encode("utf-8"))
'0019003Z00000019003Z'
```

**JavaScript** has the `Intl` module, which provides collation (ordering) via `new Intl.Collator(...).compare()` but as far as I know does not expose an equivalent of `strxfrm`. I wonder if there's some fundamental difficulty with that. I wish such function was available to build e.g. custom IndexedDB indices, but alas! ‍♂️